# AutoMapper does not map type to inner type

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper to map an instance of a type to an inner type of another type.. In this example I am trying to map an instance of Org to an inner Organization property on the type CreateRequest.  I created a map profile with the following CreateMap...

```
CreateMap<Org, CreateRequest>()
```

Where CreateRequest consists of one property of type Org.

```
 public class CreateOrganizationRequest
{
    public CreateOrganizationRequest() { }

    public Org Organization { get; set; }
}
```

and Org is defined as follows;

```
 public class Org
{
    public Org() { }
        
    public string Name { get; set; }
        
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

However when I attempt the following map, it *does not* map the value of organization to the Organization property of the createRequest.

```
var organization = new Org { Name = "1234" };
var createRequest = mapper.Map<CreateOrganizationRequest>(organization);
```

I realize that it would be easiest to simply add the type however this was greatly simplified to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following;

```
 CreateMap<Org, CreateOrganizationRequest>().ForMember(dest => dest.Organization, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

This resolves my issue.